# Flutter ScrollPhysics change on Keyboard up / or other ideas?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, frontend

I want to navigate through my ListView only with two buttons, not with the fingers and scroll so:  `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`.
here is a picture, the problem is below:

[image]

when I open the keyboard, it looks like this: [image]

So my Input Fields are obscured behind the keyboard. With an active scroll physics, this wouldn't happen because it resizes the screen so that it fit. Is there a way to move the End of my scaffold to the end of the keyboard, e.g.? Or a workaround like to activate the scrolls physics only when the keyboard appears?
I also have a

```
    ScrollConfiguration(
                  behavior: MyBehavior(),

class MyBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

but I think this is not important for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if keyboard is opened like this:

```
//use flutter_keyboard_visibility plugin for detection
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';
import 'dart:async';

late StreamSubscription<bool> keyboardSubscription;
bool isKeyboardVisible = false;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  var keyboardVisibilityController = KeyboardVisibilityController();
  // Query
  print('Keyboard visibility direct query: ${keyboardVisibilityController.isVisible}');

  // Subscribe
  keyboardSubscription = keyboardVisibilityController.onChange.listen((bool visible) {
    print('Keyboard visibility update. Is visible: $visible');
    isKeyboardVisible = visible;
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
  keyboardSubscription.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

For listview :

```
physics: !isKeyboardVisible?const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics():ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: I get an error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel flutter_keyboard_visibility)

Comment: If you are using hot restart or hot reload, it won't do the trick. Since Flutter has to inject plugin dependencies into the platform-specific parts of your app, hot restart/hot reload is not enough to trigger the injection. Close the app and execute flutter run command.

Comment: Attention. I got that from another question I asked: you need to update the state in the Subscription:  `isKeyboardVisible = visible;
      setState(() { isKeyboardVisible = visible; });`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your listview in SingleChildScrollView like below,

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListView....
```